# Long precedure in timer's callback

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer

I am working on a timer now, timers are maintained by a linked list.Like this:

```
struct timer
{
    struct timer* prev;
    struct timer* next;
    struct timespec start;
    struct timespec interval;
    void* par; 
    int (*handler) (void* par);
};
```

Then I use a thread called `dispatch` to sleep and pick timers from the list.The code is simplified as below:

```
//just pseudo code here
void dispatch() {
    for (;;) {
        while (list_empty()) {
            wait();
        }
        timer* ptr = listhead();
        if (timer_begin(ptr)) {
            ptr->handler(ptr->par);
            list_pop_front();
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**
When there is a long precedure in the callback function `handler`(say the handler function costs 500ms to execute, then `dispatch` stucks), the rest timers in the list may not be processed in time.So do we need a `thread pool` here?Or is there any other advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of long duration tasks interleaved with short duration tasks is a fundamental problem of real-time (and near-real-time) systems. Having a separate thread to handle longer running tasks, and delegating longer tasks to a second thread is a good solution.  But is your long-running task waiting on io, or just heavy processing?

Should the delay be caused by asynchronous processing (waiting on io, for example), You might split the work into a 'top-half' and a 'bottom-half', where the 'top-half' dispatches the io request, and then schedules a 'bottom-half' to check for the results.  Alternatives are to handle the signal from the response, possibly with a promise (really interesting technique).

Should the delay be cause by a processing heavy task, you might still be able to use a similar technique, by forming your compute heavy task in such a way that it 'yields' periodically.  Threading is better, but may not be available in some embedded environments.

Comment: Can you please provide some practical code or some good examples?I can not find information further more about this topic.